# Running after leg day - good or bad idea?

Tags: running, muscle-gain, recovery, legs, muscle-recovery

After I've done a leg day going heavy with squats and/or leg press, is it OK to do a 5-7k run?

I find that it's good for my mental health to have a run mixed into my routine, but I wonder if that affects recovery in a negative way.